# Solving a simply non linear system

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions, gamma

For example i have this data:

```
x-c(73,6,77,81,91,120,150,61,65,68,18,20,23,12,14,18,23,26
+26,27,2,3,3,40,41,41,6,10,11,12,37,38,38,6,73,6,51)
```

and i want to calculate the a=shape and b=scale parameters of gamma distribution. I want to solve this non-linear system

```
a*b=m1
a*b^2+(a^2)*(b^2)=m2
```

The m1 and m2 are these:

```
m1<-sum(x)/length(x)
m2<-sum((x)^2)/length(x)
```

I can solve it with hand and with calculator, but i wanna know how to instantly solve this with R

Comment: Is the `+` correct?

Comment: @Bhas Yes, the + is correct. It's from the Method of Moment. It estimates the parameters of Gamma Distribution. Take a look: http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~farhadi/ASPER/Method%20of%20Moments.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R can do this quite easily

```
library(nleqslv)
f <- function(x) {
  a<-x[1]
  b<-x[2]
  c(a*b-m1,a*b^2+(a^2)*(b^2)-m2)
}
nleqslv(c(1,30), f)
```

Output should look like:

```
$`x`
[1]  1.286486 30.595840

$fvec
[1] -9.663381e-13 -1.396074e-10

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1 1

$nfcnt
[1] 11

$njcnt
[1] 2

$iter
[1] 10
```

You can make things more robust by providing gradients. Of course R can also estimate parameters for the gamma distribution directly (e.g. `fitdistr` from the MASS package).

Comment: Is this the solution? I defined `xalt <- c(1.286486, 30.595840)` and calculated `f(xalt)` resulting in `[1]   1.063823 110.962656`. Taking `xalt` as starting value I get a slightly different solution: `[1]   1.247244 30.705526`.

Comment: @Bhas I can't reproduce your result. Copy-paste error? (I kept the + in the x data which is likely wrong).

Comment: @Kalvelagen. Wel spotted. I deleted the `+` since I thought it to be wrong. When I leave the `+` I get your result. I have just commented on the original question about this.